# how to add or concatenate percentage sign in the label value in iphone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I am using following line to show value on label but i also want that with this values it must also show percentage along with the value so how to add the percentage sign

```
   ModerateEIULabel.text=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Unvaccinated];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ModerateEIULabel.text =[ ModerateEIULabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"%"];
```

let me know it is working or not..!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 3):

To show `%` in formatted string you need to add two `%%`

```
ModerateEIULabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%",appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Unvaccinated];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two % sign to get one % sign in label..

Check using :

```
NSLog(@"%%");
```

It will print one % sign.

Answer (score 1):

just add % sign  at last in stringFormat like bellow..

```
 ModerateEIULabel.text=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%",appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Unvaccinated];
```

Comment: but its working dude where u want to show this??ModerateEIULabel.text= @"21.00%"; try this code dude..